# I want to disable export to excel from my dahsboards

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to hide or disable "Export to Excel" and "Export to PowerPoint" from my dashboards in SharePoint, precisely from the webpart menu.

Note that I am using Performance Point to create my dashboards.

Please someone helps me I am out of solutions.

Comment: hi you found the solution for your issue, i also has requirement export  reports to excel